# Capture payment method used to pay with PayPal Checkout/Orders API

Tags: javascript, paypal, payment-gateway, payment-processing, paypal-buttons

I'm using the Standard Integration of PayPal Checkout (via the Orders API), and want to capture the actual payment method - which I believe PayPal calls a "funding source" - that the customer paid with, so that I can pass this value to my server and persist it to my database.

What API object do I need to call to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [JS SDK buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) that call your server, you can track which button on your site was clicked by passing an `onClick` function; its first parameter will be an object with `fundingSource` set to e.g. "paypal", "venmo", "card", "paylater". Have it store this to a global or w/e and then you can include this in the JSON body sent to your server when capturing an order from onApprove.

However, the actual funding method that the payer ended up using might not correspond to that initial click selection, and is not returned; this and all other billing information is kept private to the payer in PayPal by design.

Comment: When you say "this and all other billing information is kept private to the payer in PayPal by design", you mean for the standard integration, right? Because according to your [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70809975/1191147), this functionality is available for the Advanced Checkout integration, although nowhere is that documented in the Orders API documentation. In any case, it seems this isn't really PayPal keeping this private "by design" (because it's already in the API) so much as it is them not bothering to expose this information for the standard integration.

Comment: *PayPal Checkout* keeps billing information private, by design. Advanced is a separate add-on integration, you'll always know when it's used since the methods or request you call are different; there is a payment_source object

Comment: I'm using the Advanced integration, and payment_source is NEVER Card, even when a credit card is used (via the credit card form). I've seen PayPal, Venmo and Apple Pay but not Card. PayPal's documentation is atrocious.

Comment: Haven't looked at it recently but that does not sound like advanced to me

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar approach to the one that Preston outlines, and in the same way it has the limitation that **it only returns the funding source of the button that's initially selected** rather than the one that the user actually paid with (as this can be changed by the user from within the PayPal modal).

It seems that this is currently the closest that those using the [Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) integration of PayPal Checkout can get to obtaining the payment method the user actually paid with because, for some reason, PayPal only sees it necessary to expose that information (which does exist in the API) to developers who have implemented the [Advanced](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/) integration.

This is a disappointment if you're someone like me who's invested considerable time in integrating the Standard integration only to find out too late (thanks to poor documentation of both the integrations and the API) that the Standard integration can only access a crippled version of the API that has limited data.

---

**In your client-side JavaScript,** add `fundingSource: fundingSource` and any other variables you want to grab from the order data:

```
paypal.Buttons({

...

onApprove: function (data, actions) {
    return fetch("/route/to/paypal/capture", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            fundingSource: fundingSource, 
            // Add any other variables you need here
        }),
    })

...
```

**Then, when capturing the payment on your server, use:**

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
...
$payment_method = $data["fundingSource"];
```

Comment: The Advanced integration is an extension / "add on" to a standard integration that, yes,  lets you know when its "advanced" card path is used --- however, when using advanced, the standard "PayPal" path will always be integrated and available regardless, and within that path any funding source can be used, including Pay Later, bank accounts, PayPal balance, local funding sources, saved credit cards, or even no-account guest credit card payments (when available)

Comment: @PrestonPHX I'm not sure how that contradicts anything I said in the answer.

Comment: It's important to understand that Advanced is a superset of a Standard integration, requires integrating Standard first, and only behaves differently when the card form is used.